# A React-native app as an action extension (IOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactjs, react-native, native

So I've followed this tutorial: https://www.promptworks.com/blog/building-ios-app-extensions-with-react-native.

All OK and working. I get my React Native view to show when I click the app in the action extension list in Safari. However, now I'm trying to actually pass the input props down to my view from my Obj C code. I would expect a URL to be passed through.

I've got the following ObjC code which handles the extension:

```
 (void)loadView {
  NSURL *jsCodeLocation;

  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];

  NSExtensionItem *item = self.extensionContext.inputItems;

  NSDictionary *initialProps =  @{ @"isActionExtension" : @(YES), @"args" : item };

  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBundleURL:jsCodeLocation
                                                      moduleName:@"mobileapp"
                                               initialProperties:initialProps
                                                   launchOptions:nil];
  rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];
  self.view = rootView;
  actionViewController = self;
}
```

No matter what I set as item (inputItems, inputItems.firstObject) - I've used many action extension posts for reference, it's always passed as NULL to my react native view.

My opening view is simply:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const { isActionExtension, args } = this.props;

    if (isActionExtension) {
      return <Text style={{ marginTop: 50 }}>{JSON.stringify(args)}</Text>;
    }

    return (
      <MenuProvider>
        <Root />
      </MenuProvider>
    );
  }
}

App.propTypes = {
  isActionExtension: PropTypes.bool,
  args: PropTypes.any
};

App.defaultProps = {
  isActionExtension: false
};
```

Note: my isActionExtension prop is passed through correctly. Any ideas?

Alex